# Storing a large amount of state in a service fabric cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a scenario where we need to store x*100 GBs of data. The data is in-general a good candidate for persistent state for an actor (well-partitioned, used by the specific actors only) in the service fabric cluster itself.

Is the service fabric persistent state storage recommended for data of this scale? (Our compute load is going to be fairly low, so bumping up VMs just to store the state is not a desirable option.)

How does the amount of persistent state affect the latency of moving partitions between nodes in the cluster?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well let's look at how state is stored in a service (this applies to actors too).

The component that stores your data in your service is called a State Provider. State providers can be in-memory only or in-memory + local disk. The default state provider you get with an actor service is in-memory + local disk but it only keeps hot data in memory so your storage requirements are not memory bound. Contrast with the Reliable Collections state provider which currently stores all data both in-memory and on local disk, although in a future release it will also have an option to only keep hot data in memory and offload the rest to local disk.

Given that you are using actors, you can use the default actor state provider which means your data capacity is limited by local disk storage on your machines or VMs, which should be reasonable for storing 100s of GB. We generally don't move entire partitions around, but occasionally Service Fabric does need to rebuild a replica of your service, and the more data you have the longer it will take to build a replica. However, this doesn't really affect the latency of your service, because you have multiple replicas in a stateful service and you usually have enough replicas up that you don't need to wait for another to be rebuilt. Rebuilding a replica is usually something that happens "off to the side."

It's true that it's not economical to add VMs just for storing state, but keep in mind that you can pack as many services onto your VMs as you want. So even though your actor service isn't using much compute, you can always pack other services on those VMs to use up that compute so that you're maximizing both compute and storage on your VMs, which can in fact be very economical.