# Persisting state to attached disks in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-resource-manager

I can create a virtual machine scale set with attached disks, thereby adding virtually unlimited cheap storage potential to my cluster. However, by default Azure Service Fabric stores all its data on the OS drive. How can I override that?

**CORRECTION:** Azure Service Fabric stores its data on the temporary disk (the D: drive), not the OS disk. I still desire the ability to select a different (larger) disk.

My service is not a good candidate for ["packing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143475/storing-a-large-amount-of-state-in-a-service-fabric-cluster) yet -- at this time I do not have a mix of compute-heavy and storage-heavy services that could share a larger VM size, and cost is the primary concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this is only possible via custom ARM templates. In those, one can define additional data disks and move the Service Fabric data directory to one of those. Standard or Premium SSDs seem to work fine like that.

Comment: I struggle to create custom ARM template to manage this situation. Anyone can share a sample ?

Comment: It's just a relatively quick export but this was my template that I used successfully last year: https://github.com/nmehlei/servicefabric-arm-template (just fill in the values in the parameters.json file)

Comment: Hi Pharao. I look for your github repo then in your template.json and paramter .json but i did not find how you did the disk persistency. Could you help ?

Comment: @terry I added a few descriptions in the Readme file of the larger steps that I still remember, basically one has to attach the disk, initialize it (with a powershell script) and move the Service Fabric directory to the new disk.